# Creating a horizontal fluid layout in css that works like a table

Tags: html, css

Basically what i am after is a fluid solution in css, that is similar to the table layout below.The principal behind this layout is 3x3 grid where by a user can add content into the first fluid area and it will expand the complete width of the page. But if that user decides that he wants content in the 2nd and 3rd area, all 3 td's fill up 33% of the width.

Effectively what i am asking is how do i create a css based layout that can do the same as the table layout?

```
     <table width="100%">
     <tr>
      <td id="leftZone" >
      fluid area here
      </td>
      <td >
        fluid area here
      </td>  
      <td id="rightZone">
      fluid area here
      </td>
     </tr>
     </table>
     <table width="100%"> 
     <tr>
      <td valign="top" >
      fluid area here
      </td>
      <td >
     fluid area here
      </td> 
      <td >
      fluid area here
      </td>
     </tr> 
     </table>
     <table width="100%">  
     <tr>
      <td >
       fluid area here
      </td>
      <td >
       fluid area here
      </td> 
      <td >
       fluid area here
      </td>
     </tr>
     </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are referring to the holy grail of layouts. Check out these resources on the topic:

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-3-column-holy-grail-pixels.htm

Comment: Unfortunately the holy grail wont work. HG relies on a fixed width for each div will wont work in my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a better way to do this, but this was my first idea.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head><style type="text/css">
    div
    {
        display: table;
    }
    div p
    {
        display: table-cell;
    }
</style></head>
<body>
<div>
    <p>1 fluid area here</p>
    <p>2 fluid area here</p>
    <p>3 fluid area here</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>4 fluid area here</p>
    <p>5 fluid area here</p>
    <p>6 fluid area here</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>7 fluid area here</p>
    <p>8 fluid area here</p>
    <p>9 fluid area here</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This might work.I need to try it out and modifiy it a bit. Will let you know

Comment: Ok it works with my modified code too, but not IE. Haven't look at safari or opera yet but i'm not fussed on them. My modification only involves changing the <p> to <div>'s and adding borders to see how they actually look.